# Powershell windows unable to run

Tags: windows, powershell, terminal

I tried running the windows PowerShell and it gives me this error, in VS Code I can't open terminal.
I haven't coded from 2 months before that it was working fine, maybe it could be due to any windows update?

[image: PowerShell]

Few things I have tried fixing this:

- Reinstalling
- Restarting
- Tried `sfc` and `dism` scans.

[image: PowerShell Apps]

There are two `PowerShell` icons in my pc the one with x86 is working fine and opening.

Comment: Please post the error message as text, rather than images

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/995714)

Comment: What did you get when you googled the error code?

Comment: they were saying restarting and reinstalling .NET framework 
running some sfc and dism scans i did everything but nothing worked